# When is the appropriate time to absolutely position an element?

Tags: jquery, css, position

### Specific Problem

**Background**

My webpage, simplified a little, looks like this:

1. Title
2. Large image
3. Text box

I'm trying to use jquery to position a div directly above the text box.  My code looks something like this (using the position API: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Position):

```
div.position({
    my: "left bottom",
    at: "left top",
    of: textbox,
});
```

where div has `position: absolute` so as not to interfere with the flow of the page.

**Problem**

My problem is that even when I do this positioning on `document.ready`, the div appears in the middle of the image, as though it were positioned relative to the textbox before the image was rendered.

In fact, if I print out the `textbox.offset()` during the `document.ready()` function and again by typing `$('#textbox').offset()`, I get two different results: the first seems to be the offset of the textbox before the image is loaded while the second is the proper offset.

### General Question

So my question is, **is there an event I can subscribe to to know when the offset data for the textbox (generally, all elements on the page) will be correct?**  Or am I missing something really basic?  I feel like I'm doing something wrong since this is the second time I've encountered this problem with images.  I'd prefer to stay away from "unclean" solutions like waiting after `document.ready` for some fixed amount of time or interacting with the image itself.

Thanks!

Comment: Probably need to see your HTML as I cant get a clear picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(document).ready()` is designed to be a convenient alternative to using `window.onload`, since in most cases all you need is for the DOM to be set up before your functions fire (so there's no need to wait for stuff like image loading, etc).  However, there are cases, and I think yours is one, where `window.onload` is, in fact, what you want.

Comment: `window.onload` is the more well-known name for that event. I'm not even sure `document.onload` will work reliably cross-browser. I'm sure `window.onload` will.

Comment: Yep, this was the problem.  I never realized they were two different events *d'oh* :) Thanks!

Comment: Doh!  I meant `window.onload`, of course.  Changed to reflect.

Answer (score 3):

I believe Jacob's answer would make it work. But some explaining would help.

`onready` fires when the DOM can be manipulated. It fires before all the images and css have been loaded. In your case, you need the image to be loaded so that the browser can properly detect its width and height.

`onload` fires after all the images load. That's why your offset would be correct after that event. If you don't want to wait for all the images to load, you could call your positioning code in that image's load event.

I would suggest trying to set the image's width and height inline `<img src='' width='' height=''>`, so the browser doesn't have to wait to download the image though. Then you could just call it in response to the `ready` event.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and suggestion, I wish I could vote this up :)

Comment: Did you try setting width and height? I think that would be the best solution to the problem if it works